# Mirror rsnapshot backup directory

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync

I would like to mirror a backup directory used by rsnapshot to a second location for more security. Ideally the solution would use rsync with ssh. What arguments do I need to provide to rsync to preserve the hardlinks (created by rsnapshot) and symlinks, to delete files, copy recursively, to delete files in the target, etc? The files are all on ext3 file systems.  Furthermore what can I do to avoid the possibility that if the source is corrupted the defects are rsynced to the mirror?

Comment: I found that there is a script called rsnapshot-copy which is intended for  initial sync: [rsnapshot-copy](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DCANTRELL/App-Rsnapshot-1.999_00002/utils/rsnapshot-copy). In the header of this file it states: `rsnapshot-copy currently is not designed for incremental mirroring of a snapshot
root (though an incremental mode may be added in the future).` Any ideas how to support this?

Comment: A further idea is to use the rsnapshot log files (maybe first modify the internal logging routines accordingly) to create a shell script which executes exactly the same mv and rsync operations rsync has performed on the primary backup also for the mirror copy of the backup.

Comment: To clarify a little, where I see the problem with a normal rsync (see answer below). If a file in the rsnapshot paths gets corrupted (e.g. due to disk failure), due to the use of hard links it will be corrupted in all newer snapshots unless it was changed somewhen later. This means the file is lost. If I do a regular automatic rsync to a mirror copy of the backup, I will eventually overwrite the file on the mirror with its corrupted version without noticing. The question is if there is a solution which avoids this.

Answer (score 7):

I think the options to do what you want are largely documented in the `rsync` man page.  In particular, the `-H` option (`--hard-links`) enables hard-link detection, and `--delete` will cause rsync to delete things on the destination that do not exist on the source.  So maybe something like:

```
rsync -aH --delete /path/to/src/ /path/to/destination
```

> Furthermore what can I do to avoid the possibility that if the source is corrupted the defects are rsynced to the mirror?

Well, that's tricky.  How do you detect corruption?  I think the only real solution is to stagger the backup of your backup (that is, perform you actual backups to your primary destination, and then rsync that to your secondary destination immediately prior to your next backup run).  This way if you detect a problem you have until the next backup run to bring things back.

A different solution would be to have `rsnapshot` back up to multiple destinations, so that you're actually generating backups from your original source in two distinct locations.  This way if one becomes damaged the second should be unaffected.

Comment: Sure all the options are in the man page. I merely wanted to make sure that I do not forget any. But the -a option seems to be pretty compact. The rsnapshot to two locations won't be feasible since the two destinations will not be available at the same time. Wouldn't it be possible to rsync allways just the newer snapshots to the mirror? This way older snapshots in this location would be preserved even if they are corrupted in the primary location. Of course I would need to repeate the renaming which is performed by rsnapshot when it adds a snapshot ...

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the copy of corrupt data you could keep a weekly backup and hope that you would notice the corruption at the source before you lost all of your backups. The best way would be to use -c and then it will compare check sums of both source and destination to determine whether to copy the file. The only down side is that it must read the whole file making the backup a slower process.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Create a Backup of Today
# Definitions
sevendaysago=$(date --date='6 days ago' +%Y-%m-%d-%A)
# Delete backups from 7 days ago
rm -rf /storage/backups/$sevendaysago
mkdir -p /storage/backups/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/$host/$username

rsync -aHvz /storage/`date --date=yesterday +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date --date=yesterday +\%A`/$host/$user/ /storage/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/$host/$user/

rsync -acHvz -e ssh --delete --exclude='logs' tim@tim.tim.net:/home/tim/ /storage/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/$host/$user/
```